# Android Google play : new app, use previous obb. Not working

Tags: android, google-play

I have successfully published an app along with an obb onto google play.

The obb was named `main.1.com.myapp.obb`, it worked fine.

Then I have done some bug fixes in the app. The obb didn't change. When uploading apk with version code 2 of my app and in the Google Play console it asked for the extension file. I could upload a new obb or use `main.1.com.myapp.obb`. I chose the latter.

After downloading the new version of the app, I see that the app works except for the parts that need the resources in the obb.

**My solution for now** : I uploaded version code 3 of the app and a copy of the original obb with name `main.3.com.myapp.obb`. (works ok)

However the obb file is big and it would be better not to have to redownload it again.

What should I do ? Should I name the file differently ?

**Notes** : I have tried this more than once, I am at version code 14 and always had the problem. I have read carefully [Google's APK Expansion Files documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)

Don't hesitate to migrate this question if it doesn't belong to here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was in the documentation you read, but it's easy to miss it.

> #### File name format
>
> ... Regardless of the file type, Google Play considers them opaque binary
>   blobs and renames the files using the following scheme:
>
> ```
> [main|patch].<expansion-version>.<package-name>.obb
> ```
>
> There are three components to this scheme:
>   ...
>   `<expansion-version>`
>   This is an integer that matches the version code of the APK with which the expansion is first associated
>   (it matches the application's `android:versionCode` value).
>
> "First" is emphasized because although the Developer Console allows you to re-use an uploaded expansion file with a new APK, the expansion file's name does not change—it retains the version applied to it when you first uploaded the file.

In other words, version 2 of your app needed to load the file using filename `main.1.com.myapp.obb`. It doesn't get renamed when the app is updated. This is unfortunate if you're updating your version code automatically with a CI server, but that's the way it goes.

Comment: thanks for the answer but that's what I think I did (see ... "I chose the latter") (was long ago)

Comment: I interpreted that to mean that in the Developer Console you told Google to include `main.1.com.myapp.obb` when someone installed version 2, but I suspect that the code was looking for `{ExternalStorageDirectory}/Android/obb/com.myapp/main.2.com.myapp.obb` on the SD card. That's certainly how I ran into the same problem...